# Concrete solution to the (oriented) Oberwolfach problem with one table

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle

I asked the following on MSE, but it received little attention...

The oriented Oberwolfach problem (with only one table) and its solution are the following.

In a meeting of $n$ people during $n-1$ days (combinatorists at Oberwolfach for concreteness), they all have diner around one table.
As these people only speak to their right neighbour, they want to be seated each day with a different right neighbour. For which $n$ is this possible?

The answer is : this is always possible unless $n=4$ or $n=6$, as stated in this other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552096/round-robin-party-presents-or-graeco-latin-square-with-additional-cycle-proper .

This can be rephrased abstractly in terms of graph theory (see the answer to the question above) as follows: find  a decomposition of the directed complete graph $K_n^*$ into directed cycles all having length $n$.

My question is : if $n=p$ is a prime, then one can use multiplication by the $p-1$ units in $\mathbf F_p$ to build a solution.

However, for other values of $n$, I don't know (and I didn't find it in the papers solving the problem, although it must be in there somewhere) how to build solutions.

For example, can anyone explain to me how to build a solution for $n=8$ (if possible with a strategy no too *ad hoc*)?\

**Edit:** I found (in the reference indicated in the comments above) a solution for $n=8$: it is :

$$(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1) \\  (1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 1)\\ (1, 4, 2,
5, 7, 3, 8, 6, 1)\\ (1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 1)\\ (1, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 5, 3, 1)\\ (1, 7, 6,3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1) \\ (1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 1)$$
I don't really understand the pattern...

Comment: "people only speak to their right neighbour" - why is it natural assumption? My left neighbour speaks something to me, but I can not answer until he becomes my right neighbour?

Comment: There is of course a non-oriented variant of the problem. I'll be glad to hear about it as well.

Comment: Which papers did you look through that solve the problem without providing a concrete construction?

Comment: One reference is : Alspach, Brian; Gavlas, Heather; Šajna, Mateja; Verrall, Helen Cycle decompositions. IV. Complete directed graphs and fixed length directed cycles. J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 103 (2003), no. 1, 165–208. But then one has to remount to older and older papers, treating special cases or equivalent problems.

Comment: Actually, there is a concrete solution for $n=8$ on page 3 of Bermond, J.-C.; Faber, V., Decomposition of the complete directed graph into k-circuits.J. Combinatorial Theory Ser. B 21 (1976), no. 2, 146–155. But they say it was found on a computer so it does not help that much.